# Equivalent Conditions for Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

We have random variable $V$ and two independent random vectors $U_1$ and $U_2$. How to prove that
$$ E(V\mid U_1,U_2)=E(V\mid U_1) \Leftrightarrow \forall t_1, E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) = E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}) $$

Comment: Just a nitpick: it's [bad practice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510219/21813) to place the quantifier at the end of the sentence, particularly when there are multiple quantifiers.

Comment: @ryang You mean $\forall t_1$?

Comment: Yea (maybe point #4 of [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474929/21813) is easier to understand). That comma also makes no sense grammatically. But this is just nitpicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have suppose that $E(V\mid U_1,U_2)=E(V\mid U_1)$ then by interverting $U_1$ with $U_2$ we get
$E(V\mid U_2,U_1)=E(V\mid U_2).$

In the other hand, $Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}$ and $U_2$ are independent since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent.

Then
\begin{align*}
 E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2)=& e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}E(V\mid U_2)\\
=&e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}E(V\mid U_1,U_2)\\
=&e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}E(V\mid U_1)\\
=&E( e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle} V\mid U_1)\\
=E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle})
\end{align*}
since    $e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}$ is $\sigma(U_1)$ measurable.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$:
\begin{align*}
E(V\mid U_1,U_2)=&E(V\mid U_1) \\
\Rightarrow E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) =& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2, U_1)\mid U_2) \\
=& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(V\mid U_2, U_1)e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) \\
=& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(V\mid U_1)e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) \\
=& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(V\mid U_1)e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}) \\
=& E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle})
\end{align*}

$\Leftarrow$:
$$\forall t_1, E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) = E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle})$$
LHS:
\begin{align*}
& E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) \\
=& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2, U_1)\mid U_2) \\
=& E_{U_1}(E_{V}(V\mid U_2, U_1)e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_2) \\
=& \int E(V\mid U_1=u_1,U_2) e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle} dF_{U_1}(u_1) \quad\quad (U_1, U_2\text{ independent}) \quad\quad (1)
\end{align*}
RHS:
\begin{align*}
& E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}) \\
=& E(E(Ve^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}\mid U_1)) \\
=& E(E(V\mid U_1)e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle}) \\
=& \int E(V\mid U_1=u_1) e^{i\langle t_1,U_1\rangle} dF_{U_1}(u_1) \quad\quad (2)
\end{align*}

We can see (1) and (2) as Fourier transformation, which is a one-to-one map. Since (1)=(2) holds for any $t_1$, we can say the original functions before Fourier transformation are the same, hence, $E(V\mid U_1,U_2)=E(V\mid U_1)$.