# What does the word 'with' mean in this theorem?

Tags: logic, logic-translation, article-writing

> If $a, b$ and $c$ are positive integers with $a, b ≥ 2$, then equation (1.1) has at most one solution in positive integers $x$ and $y$ **with**
> $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}.$

I'm unclear about the above usage of the word '**with**'; is this theorem saying

**IF** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}$ **THEN** equation (1.1) has at most one solution

or

**IF** equation (1.1) has at most one solution **THEN** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)},$

or

is it an **IFF** statement?

Comment: "With" should be interpreted as "under the condition that..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > If $a, b$ and $c$ are positive integers with $a, b ≥ 2$, then equation (1.1) has at most one solution in positive integers $x$ and
> > $y$ **with** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}.$

In the above theorem, the two copies of `with` both have a logical '**and**' sense and can be replaced with the phrase 'such that':

- If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers **such that** neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1,$ then if $x$ and $y$ are positive integers **such that** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)},$ then equation (1.1) has at most one solution
- $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers **and** neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1\quad\implies$

  ($x$ and $y$ are positive integers **and** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}$ $\implies$ equation (1.1) has at most one solution)
- $a,b,c,x$ and $y$ are positive integers  and  neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1$  and  $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}\quad\quad\implies$ equation (1.1) has at most one solution.

> is this theorem saying
>
> **IF** $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}$ **THEN**

No. That implicit conditional (the second '⟹' in the second bullet) above is actually not due to the word `with` per se, because its condition is actually the entire chunk “in positive integers $x$ and $y$ with $b^y ≥ 6000 c^{1/δ∗(a,b)}\,$”.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4266064/21813), I explain why the words `with` and `where` are frequently ambiguous in logic translations.